# Creating a Window 10 Pro VM on a Window 10 Pro, with hyper V

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

On my computer with Windows 10 Pro, I wish to create a virtual machine with Windows 10 Pro. I seem to be unable to do this, as I can only create the following OS's.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is possible, and whether my license for Window Pro can transfer to the virtual machine. In short, I hope to "partition off" part of my machine into a virtual machine.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you even seeing this window? No, Microsoft licenses are only valid for one installation. Unless you’re trying to make your current Windows a VM, in which case you would then not have Windows on the host.

Comment: Hyper-V quick create.

Comment: I see. You don’t have to use this wizard. You can always create a Hyper-V VM with any supported operating system, which of course includes Windows 10 Pro. You’ll have to use the regular installation method. A VM is just “a PC” after all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a Windows 10 Pro VM on Windows 10 Pro.

Step

- download iso file for windows 10 pro, [link](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10)
- in "Select an operating system" window, choose your iso, [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/quick-create-virtual-machine).

And about your license, it depend on your license type. If "full retail copy" license you can transfer it. If OEM license, you can't. 
[transfer windows 10 license to new pc](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/transfer-windows-10-license-new-pc/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your post to quote the relevant information from your links which confirms these assertions? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to super user. I cannot find any place in that link where the author talks about creating a Window 10 Pro VM on Window 10 Pro.

Comment: You don't need to use quick create. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/create-virtual-machine  You will need a separate license for your VM, you can't use the one installed on your physical computer.  You will also need to download an ISO of Windows 10 (or have a physical DVD) to boot from.